# How do I set automatic captions on and select a language by default?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

The parameters *cc_lang_pref* and *cc_load_policy=1* only work for languages added by the video owner.

I want to select a default language from the auto-translate list for a video with English (auto-generated).
Is there a way to do this by URL, API or some other settings?

Any help is gratefully received.